# How to select first bold words from sentence by php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I want to select first bold words from sentence.

If my sentence is `<b>My username here</b> Address: <b>Bangladesh.</b> Mobile: <b>xxxxxx</b>`

Here I want to output just: `My username here`

I read about preg_match, explode but cannot understand how to apply them.

Comment: you must use regex .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only first bold section then use below code.

```
<?php
$text = '<b>My username here</b> Address: <b>Bangladesh.</b> Mobile: <b>xxxxxx</b>';
preg_match("'<b>(.*?)</b>'si", $text, $match);

echo $match[0];
?>
```

for all bold search use this

```
<?php
$text = '<b>My username here</b> Address: <b>Bangladesh.</b> Mobile: <b>xxxxxx</b>';
preg_match_all("'<b>(.*?)</b>'si", $text, $match);

foreach($match[1] as $val)
{
    echo $val.' ';
}
?>
```

[Here is the sample](https://eval.in/484423)

Comment: Never ever use regex to parse HTML .

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplest way :

```
$text = "<b>My username here</b> Address: <b>Bangladesh.</b> Mobile: <b>xxxxxx</b>";
preg_match("/<b>(.*?)<\\/b>/", $text, $match);

echo $match[0];
```